# Get second Onclicklistener values

Tags: android, string, firebase-realtime-database, onclick, getvalue

I have  String values in firebase database 
I would like to get this String 
in onClick i make a toast for display the value but the value is toasted in the second click

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_souslistecuisine);
    cuisinecomplet=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cuisinecomplett);

    FirebaseDatabase database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef=database.getReference("Produit");
    DatabaseReference key=myRef.child("Cuisine");
    DatabaseReference text=key.child("cuisine complet");
    text1=text.child("text1");
    text1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            txt=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



}
public void complet(View view) {

    Toast.makeText(souslistecuisine.this, txt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

I tried to put `text1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener())`  in `Onclick` method but same result

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `Toast` after you already receive the String value from `Firebase`, as `Firebase` callbacks run in background thread and take time to response.

```
text1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        txt=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        Toast.makeText(souslistecuisine.this, txt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: thank you but I put toast just to test but really in on click I want to edit an edit text by the value of txt, I don't know why it works in the second on click ?

Comment: @OuertaniSaiid So the problem is that the first click on the button has no effect, but the second displayed the toast right?